# In Unity, why can I switch the Camera to WorldView with a button press but cannot do it in the Start or Update loop while also using Face Manager?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm working on a Unity AR game in which I'd like to start out using the Face Manager to track Face Pose on the World-Facing Camera. I know for a fact that you can track Face Pose with the World Camera because I've seen it in the ar-foundation-samples project. The one caveat to that is that you have to start in User-Facing Mode first, then press a button to switch to World-Facing mode once the app is running. I'd like for it to start out on World-Facing camera, but every time I try to do this with the Face Manager running, it doesn't work; the camera doesn't come on at all. My question is, why can I switch my face pose tracking from User-Facing to World-Facing with a button click, yet I can't do the same via the Start() or Update() methods?

```
public class FaceController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        /*This won't switch the camera*/        
        camManager.requestedFacingDirection = CameraFacingDirection.World;
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        
    }

    public ARCameraManager camManager;
    public ARSession aRSession;
    bool trigger;
    bool trigger2;

    public void SwitchMode()
    {
        /*This will switch the camera when called by a button press */
        camManager.requestedFacingDirection = CameraFacingDirection.World;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
      
      
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly does `This doesn't work` mean? Getting errors?

Comment: The camera won't switch from User to World

Comment: is maybe something else overwriting it back to `User`?

Comment: I don't know. I think that may be the case, but that's part of my question here, what could be doing that and how can I stop it?

Comment: From [ARCameraManager.currentFacingDirection](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@4.0/api/UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation.ARCameraManager.html#UnityEngine_XR_ARFoundation_ARCameraManager_currentFacingDirection): The current camera facing direction. This should usually match `requestedFacingDirection` but may be different if **the platform cannot service the requested camera facing direction, or it may take a few frames for the requested facing direction to become active.** .. could this be the case?

Comment: Maybe. I'd really love to know when exactly it becomes active though, or what exactly constitutes a "few frames."

Comment: I guess you would just need to wait until `currentFacingDirection == requestFacingDirection` e.g. in a Coroutine using `WaitUntil`

Comment: No dice. I'm going to try waiting a few frames in before requesting the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered that you could only switch cameras AFTER frame 1 had passed. Per *derHugo*'s comment below, I think the best solution is a coroutine as follows:

```
IEnumerator switchCamera()
{

    yield return null;
    yield return null;
    camManager.requestedFacingDirection = CameraFacingDirection.World;
    
}
```

Comment: In that case a coroutine skipping the two frames via two `yield return null;` lines would probably be more convenient in order to not have an Update method running for the rest of the time without use ;)

Comment: Possible btw that this is related to the ARFoundation subservice lifecycle and maybe it always takes the first frames to initialize the service itself before booting the subservices..

Comment: I figured as much. I did read that these features are at the end of the day merely requests that may or may not be granted. There just seems to be scant documentation on exactly how long the requests take to process and when you can pose a new one.